# SUM of tableA with LEFT JOIN tableB also counts all tableB

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, grouping

I have a table `A`

[image: Table A data]

and a related table `B`

[image: Table B data]

joined by a unique ID in table `A`
I want to count the rows in table `A` and also count the rows in table `A` where there is a related table `B`

I have the query

```
SELECT NameID,Area,Area !="" AS Kount, 
b.tableaID > 0 AS `Visted`
FROM `tablea` a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb b ON a.ID=b.tableaID 
GROUP BY a.ID,b.tableaID,Area
```

This gives me a list of NameIDs and areas each showing once but obviously only a 1 in Kount and Visited.

[image: First Result]

As soon as I add a sum on Kount eg.

```
SELECT NameID,Area,SUM(Area !="") AS Kount, 
SUM(b.tableaID > 0) AS `Visted`
FROM `tablea` a 
LEFT OUTER JOIN tableb b ON a.ID=b.tableaID 
GROUP BY a.ID,b.tableaID,Area
```

I get a count of all table 'B' as well even thought I have groups in place.
[image: Second sql]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: OK I understand.

Comment: I have now tested my revised database/query but I am told I can no longer post to the forum!  What do I need to do please

Comment: It says I should improve the question, but I don't think there is enough space in the comments section

Comment: Apologies, I will get to work :-)

Comment: Hey BB, nowhere in that linked answer does it suggest that posting images of text is an appropriate way forward. In fact, it specifcally advises against it.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by a pre-query of tableB grouped by the tableA ID column.  Now go back to the original tableA and LEFT-JOIN to tableB prequery result.

```
select
      A.*,
      coalesce( BQry.bRecs, 0 ) as NumBRecords
   from
      tableA A
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select
                    tableaID,
                    count(*) bRecs
                from
                    tableB
                group by
                    tableaID ) BQry
        on A.id = BQry.tableaID
```

Now, the table "A" side has an ID, which I would suspect is a primary key and never have any duplicates of the "ID" in this table.  So grouping the inner "BQry" table by that ID is the basis of the join as your left-join had.  The "A" side would always be a 1 count as it IS the record basis of the query.

The Coalesce() for the BQry records will be 0 if no such match on tableAID, and the actual count if so found.

And for future, don't try to expand answer in comments... Just edit your existing post and add additional details to it.

**REVISION**

After re-looking, I saw you were not doing the outer sum based on tableA ID, but the name in TableID.  Multiple tableAIDs could have the same name reference.

```
select
      A.NameID,
      A.Area,
      count(*) as NameCounts,
      sum( coalesce( BQry.bRecs, 0 )) as NumBRecords
   from
      tableA A
         LEFT JOIN
         ( select
                    tableaID,
                    count(*) bRecs
                from
                    tableB
                group by
                    tableaID ) BQry
        on A.id = BQry.tableaID
```

group by
      A.NameID,
      A.Area

Comment: Many thanks for the advice.  I will try your suggestion, thank you

Comment: @BinaryBridge, after re-reading and getting power back, took a look and revised query to get proper sum by the names / areas WITHIN all tableA records, not just per tableAID.  Please take a look.